# why need to change url when we are working with ajax

Tags: ajax

why it's need to change URL when we are working with AJAX ? as example when google translate start translate phrase or word change URL? whereas all information are sending and receiving using AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL is not required to change. Google does this for convenience so that you can share the link to the translation with another person.